# Layout with Bootstrap grid system

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, layout, responsive-design

I've been trying to upgrade my website into mobile supported one, i thought it was a good idea to learn Bootstrap on the way. I've watched and read many tutorials but i'm still lost about grids. Here is the thing i'm trying to do basically, it's a simplified version ofcourse:

[Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NC6Gs.jpg)

As you can see, i will add some bars to the left and products will be on right. I want to have at least 2 columns in smallest devices, i want 3 columns on other devices.In those columns i will have multiple bars and products. I've tried many things without success. I'm not trying to get the code, like i said it's only a small part of the website, i'm trying to understand it.

Any ideas, examples or tutorials?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To better understand Bootstrap's grids, I suggest you download one of their starter templates and check the source code. It will make you clear of all the doubts you have. What you have here is too generic.

I'll give you an idea:

If you want an element to be 4 columns on large screens, 6 columns on medium screens and 12 columns on small screens, here's what you do:

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
       Your content here
</div>
```

This will make your grid instantly responsive. Try this on different columns to get a better understanding.

Comment: Thanks, i actually find almost an exact same thing i'm trying to do there. I'm trying to understand that now.

Comment: The bootstrap grid has 12 columns with a container of 1170px I guess. So you can split these columns to form your content. What col-lg-4 means is that make my content only 4 columns on large screens (PCs), and col-md-4 means make it 4 columns on Laptops too. col-sm-6 means make the content 6 columns when the user is on a tablet and col-sm-12 means make the content 12 columns on a small screen (mobile phones). It does take a few hours to understand, but you are on the right track. All the best.

Answer (score 0):

For the columns I would check out this page: http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp. In addition to what @TheEarlyMan said, if you want to nest columns inside each other, you just need to create another div inside the 'container' div and just make sure the column widths add up to 12.

For example, here's some code I modified from here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h1>Grid</h1>
  <p>This example demonstrates a 50%/50% split on small, medium and large devices. On extra small devices, it will stack (100% width).</p>      
  <p>Resize the browser window to see the effect.</p>      
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:blue;">
        <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:purple;">
          First Column
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:green;">
          Second Column
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:yellow;">
          Third Column
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:red;">
        <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:pink;">
            Fourth Column 
        </div>   
        <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:lightblue;">
            Fifth Column
        </div> 

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Post that into the text box and click 'Try It' and you should see two columns, blue and red, with some nested columns inside each. The blue has three columns and the red has two.

Just fool around with it, it takes some practice to get the hang of.